Loading coil efficiency for 160 meters
I am trying to get my N1CC and would like to get on 160 meters for pota. I can get a vertical that is 39 feet tall set up at the park. I know it will be narrow banded and take a large loading coil, but will the efficiency be ok? another question is what would the radial system have to look like to work ssb? Would it be better to make a dipole or EFHW and place it at about 20 feet?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
